# Unable fetch metrics from postgresql://pgbouncer:***@vsaxx:6432/pgbouncer", "exception": "invalid integer value \"xxx\" for connection option \"port\"

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes-helm, pgbouncer

I am deploying the prometheus-pgbouncer-exporter to kubernetes by helm chart. Although pods in this namespace is running, the log of pods always show this error message, which failed to collecting metrics and these pgbouncer servers could be shown in grafana.

The original issue:

> {"asctime": "xxxx", "levelname": "ERROR", "message": "Unable fetch metrics from postgresql://pgbouncer:***@localhost:6432/pgbouncer", "exception": "could not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 6432?\ncould not connect to server: Address not available\n\tIs the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 6432?\n"}

When i try to debug and re-deploy it again, another issue occurs:

> {"asctime": "2022-04-22 08:41:33", "levelname": "ERROR", "message": "Unable fetch metrics from postgresql://pgbouncer:***@xxxx:6432/pgbouncer", "exception": "invalid integer value "AgAjp0E7ePrce41jwBgvO8" for connection option "port"\n"}

I'm really new to pgbouncer, helm chart, kubernetes and grafana.

Comment: Seem like you password has special characters in it that are interpreted as URI component separators, and so it needs to be URI (percent sign) encoded.  Also, you should probably change the password now that you have posted a segment of it on the internet.

Comment: Hi @jjanes , I also doubt if the password includes sepecial characters. Actually, this password will be a selead secret and I also could see the origin password in the kubernates dashbord.  The shown password just a piece of selead secret.  But thank you for your suggestion and I will use percent sign to have a try.

Comment: it still doesn't work... :(